# How to change RAM memory to Android emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I cannot found this file `hardware-qemu.ini` or `config.ini`

I can't create another one with more memory either, it is created by default with 1.5GB of ram

Changes is lock

[image]

Comment: This answer is still valid (select from x86 Images - not from Recommended): https://stackoverflow.com/a/52342344/17856705.

Answer (score -1):

If you create an AVD with a "Recommended" system image, then you cannot change the "Memory" parameters.

> [Select System Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FpW06.jpg)

Solution:
You should have to select your "Image" from the "x86 Images" tab and then you can change the "Memory" parameters on the next page or you can edit the "Memory" parameter in the edit AVD section.

Comment: Try not to copy answers verbatim - it's sufficient to comment as a duplicate and it will be dispositioned as such.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/52342344/17856705

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).